# selenium python element select from dropdown menu

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, select, drop-down-menu

Trying to select multiple elements from dropdown menu via selenium in python.
[Website](https://channelcrawler.com/)  from URL. But `Timeoutexception` error is occurring.

I have tried Inspect menu from GoogleChrome. `//label[@for="inputGenre"]/parent::div//select[@placeholder="Choose a Category"]` gives exactly the select tag that I need. But unfortunately, with selenium I cannot locate any element within this tag. Any ideas why the error occur?

code is below;

```
slect_element = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_located_to_be_selected((By.XPATH, '//label[@for="inputGenre"]/parent::div//select[@placeholder="Choose a Category"]'))))

slect_element.select_by_index(1)
slect_element.select_by_value('23')
```

strangeness is it is possible to locate it and get its text values from code below;

```
drp_menu=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//label[@for="inputGenre"]/parent::div//div[@class="dropdown-main"]/ul/li')
print(len(drp_menu))
ls_categories=[]
for i in drp_menu:
    ls_categories.append(i.get_attribute('innerText'))
```

print is giving 15 elements, and get_attribute(innerText) gives text of each option element text.
Anyway, Thanks a lot @Prophet

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this can help, but maybe try to put a quick sleep before the 
`slect_element.select_by_index(1)` and 
`slect_element.select_by_value('23')` ? Maybe the elements are not fully loaded when you try to execute the above commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That Select element is hidden and can't be used by Selenium as we use normal Select elements to select drop-down menu items.
Here we need to open the drop-down as we open any other elements by clicking them, select the desired options and click the Search button.
So, these lines are opening that drop down and selecting 2 options in the drop-down menu:

```py
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='form-group'][contains(.,'Category')]//div[@class='dropdown-display-label']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='form-group'][contains(.,'Category')]//li[@data-value='23']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='form-group'][contains(.,'Category')]//li[@data-value='1']"))).click()
```

The result so far is:

[image]

And by finally clicking the Search button the result is:

[image]

The entire code is:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

url = "https://channelcrawler.com/"

driver.get(url)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='form-group'][contains(.,'Category')]//div[@class='dropdown-display-label']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='form-group'][contains(.,'Category')]//li[@data-value='23']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='form-group'][contains(.,'Category')]//li[@data-value='1']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[type='submit']"))).click()
```